# get monthYear values of a range in php laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

This might be a simple one, but I've `$startYearMonth` and `$lastYearMonth` values.

```
$lastYear = 2020
$year = 2021
$month = 9
$lastYearMonth = 11 
$startYearMonth= Carbon::create($year, $month)->startOfMonth();
$lastYearMonth= Carbon::create($lastYear, $lastYearMonth)->startOfMonth();
```

How can I get all the yearMonth values in that range?

```
202011, 202012, 202101, 202102, 202103, 202104, 202105, 202106, 202107, 202108, 202109
```

What's the best way to get this array of yearMonth values?

Comment: did any of the answer below work for you ? if so, close your question by marking one of them as "The Answer"

Answer (score 1):

```php
$lastYear = 2020;
$year = 2021;
$month = 9;
$lastYearMonth = 11 ;
$startYearMonth = Carbon::create($year, $month)->startOfMonth();
$lastYearMonth = Carbon::create($lastYear, $lastYearMonth)->startOfMonth();
$yearMonths = [];

foreach ($lastYearMonth->monthsUntil($startYearMonth) as $date) {
  $yearMonths[] = $date->format('Ym');
}

echo implode(', ', $yearMonths);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fancy way using generators and iterators

```
$lastYear = 2020;
$year = 2021;
$month = 9;
$lastYearMonth = 11;

function monthPeriods($startYear, $startMonth, $endYear, $endMonth) {
    $start = new DateTime($startYear.'-'.$startMonth.'-01');
    $end = new DateTime($endYear.'-'.$endMonth.'-01');
    while ($start <= $end) {
        yield $start->format('Ym');
        $start->modify('+1 month');
    }
}

$iterator = monthPeriods($lastYear, $lastYearMonth, $year,$month);
echo implode(',', iterator_to_array($iterator));
```